# Spellchecking Challenge - Implementing a dictionary lookup

Tags: performance, c

I am trying to speed up the performance of this program.  The only file we can change is dictionary.c

The problem is basically to load a dictionary and then do a spell check on submitted text.  The approach we used was to assume the dictionary would be already sorted (it is)and then create a hash table in a trie and load the dictionary in a number of tries.  All of that to make the check function fast.  Unfortuanately, while the program runs it's performance is not that great.  You can see how it performs relative to other submissions here: https://speller.cs50.net/cs50/problems/2020/x/challenges/speller I'm listed as rsail at number 3004

speller.c

```
// Implements a spell-checker

#include <ctype.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <sys/resource.h>
#include <sys/time.h>

#include "dictionary.h"

// Undefine any definitions
#undef calculate
#undef getrusage

// Default dictionary
#define DICTIONARY "dictionaries/large"

// Prototype
double calculate(const struct rusage *b, const struct rusage *a);

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    // Check for correct number of args
    if (argc != 2 && argc != 3)
    {
        printf("Usage: ./speller [DICTIONARY] text\n");
        return 1;
    }

    // Structures for timing data
    struct rusage before, after;

    // Benchmarks
    double time_load = 0.0, time_check = 0.0, time_size = 0.0, time_unload = 0.0;

    // Determine dictionary to use
    char *dictionary = (argc == 3) ? argv[1] : DICTIONARY;

    // Load dictionary
    getrusage(RUSAGE_SELF, &before);
    bool loaded = load(dictionary);
    getrusage(RUSAGE_SELF, &after);

    // Exit if dictionary not loaded
    if (!loaded)
    {
        printf("Could not load %s.\n", dictionary);
        return 1;
    }

    // Calculate time to load dictionary
    time_load = calculate(&before, &after);

    // Try to open text
    char *text = (argc == 3) ? argv[2] : argv[1];
    FILE *file = fopen(text, "r");
    if (file == NULL)
    {
        printf("Could not open %s.\n", text);
        unload();
        return 1;
    }

    // Prepare to report misspellings
    printf("\nMISSPELLED WORDS\n\n");

    // Prepare to spell-check
    int index = 0, misspellings = 0, words = 0;
    char word[LENGTH + 1];

    // Spell-check each word in text
    for (int c = fgetc(file); c != EOF; c = fgetc(file))
    {
        // Allow only alphabetical characters and apostrophes
        if (isalpha(c) || (c == '\'' && index > 0))
        {
            // Append character to word
            word[index] = c;
            index++;

            // Ignore alphabetical strings too long to be words
            if (index > LENGTH)
            {
                // Consume remainder of alphabetical string
                while ((c = fgetc(file)) != EOF && isalpha(c));

                // Prepare for new word
                index = 0;
            }
        }

        // Ignore words with numbers (like MS Word can)
        else if (isdigit(c))
        {
            // Consume remainder of alphanumeric string
            while ((c = fgetc(file)) != EOF && isalnum(c));

            // Prepare for new word
            index = 0;
        }

        // We must have found a whole word
        else if (index > 0)
        {
            // Terminate current word
            word[index] = '\0';

            // Update counter
            words++;

            // Check word's spelling
            getrusage(RUSAGE_SELF, &before);

            bool misspelled = !check(word);

            getrusage(RUSAGE_SELF, &after);

            // Update benchmark
            time_check += calculate(&before, &after);

            // Print word if misspelled
            if (misspelled)
            {
                printf("%s\n", word);
                misspellings++;
            }

            // Prepare for next word
            index = 0;
        }
    }

    // Check whether there was an error
    if (ferror(file))
    {
        fclose(file);
        printf("Error reading %s.\n", text);
        unload();
        return 1;
    }

    // Close text
    fclose(file);

    // Determine dictionary's size
    getrusage(RUSAGE_SELF, &before);
    unsigned int n = size();
    getrusage(RUSAGE_SELF, &after);

    // Calculate time to determine dictionary's size
    time_size = calculate(&before, &after);

    // Unload dictionary
    getrusage(RUSAGE_SELF, &before);
    bool unloaded = unload();
    getrusage(RUSAGE_SELF, &after);

    // Abort if dictionary not unloaded
    if (!unloaded)
    {
        printf("Could not unload %s.\n", dictionary);
        return 1;
    }

    // Calculate time to unload dictionary
    time_unload = calculate(&before, &after);

    // Report benchmarks
    printf("\nWORDS MISSPELLED:     %d\n", misspellings);
    printf("WORDS IN DICTIONARY:  %d\n", n);
    printf("WORDS IN TEXT:        %d\n", words);
    printf("TIME IN load:         %.2f\n", time_load);
    printf("TIME IN check:        %.2f\n", time_check);
    printf("TIME IN size:         %.2f\n", time_size);
    printf("TIME IN unload:       %.2f\n", time_unload);
    printf("TIME IN TOTAL:        %.2f\n\n",
           time_load + time_check + time_size + time_unload);

    // Success
    return 0;
}

// Returns number of seconds between b and a
double calculate(const struct rusage *b, const struct rusage *a)
{
    if (b == NULL || a == NULL)
    {
        return 0.0;
    }
    else
    {
        return ((((a->ru_utime.tv_sec * 1000000 + a->ru_utime.tv_usec) -
                  (b->ru_utime.tv_sec * 1000000 + b->ru_utime.tv_usec)) +
                 ((a->ru_stime.tv_sec * 1000000 + a->ru_stime.tv_usec) -
                  (b->ru_stime.tv_sec * 1000000 + b->ru_stime.tv_usec)))
                / 1000000.0);
    }
}
```

dictionary.h

```
// Declares a dictionary's functionality

#ifndef DICTIONARY_H
#define DICTIONARY_H

#include <stdbool.h>

// Maximum length for a word
// (e.g., pneumonoultramicroscopicsilicovolcanoconiosis)
#define LENGTH 45

// Prototypes
bool check(const char *word);
unsigned int hash(const char *word);
bool load(const char *dictionary);
unsigned int size(void);
bool unload(void);

#endif // DICTIONARY_H
```

dictionary.c

// Implements a dictionary's functionality

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <fcntl.h>
#include <string.h>
#include "dictionary.h"
#include <limits.h>
#include <math.h>
#include <ctype.h>

#define MAXWORDS 200000
#define MAXBUCKETS 511

unsigned int numberOfWords = 0;
int target;
unsigned int N = 1;  //number of buckets in hash table. (a function of how big the dictionary is)


// we modified nodeWords to containe more information
typedef struct nodeWords
{
    char  *word;
    char  *wordEnd;
    int    index;
    struct nodeWords *left;
    struct nodeWords *right;
} nodeWords;

nodeWords  *headHashNode;
nodeWords **nodeArray;
nodeWords *nodeHash;
nodeWords *nodeTri;
nodeWords **nodeHistory;

int hashBuckets;

int hashFlag = 0;

char (*words)[LENGTH + 1] = NULL;


long int findSize(const char *file_name);
unsigned int size(void);
unsigned int hash(const char *word);
bool check(const char *word);
bool unload(void);

nodeWords *leftRightAddress(int buckets, nodeWords *nodeGen);
int *nextBuckets(int power, int kick, int oob, int buckets);

//used for testing
typedef struct nodeNumbers
{
    int number;
    struct nodeNumbers *left;
    struct nodeNumbers *right;
} nodeNumbers;


// Returns true if word is in dictionary else false
bool check(const char *word)
{

    // we created tries for both the hash table and dictionary

    int lc = strlen(word);;
    char  *lcWord = malloc(46);


    for (int i = 0; i < lc; i++)
    {

        lcWord[i] = tolower(word[i]);
    }
    lcWord[lc] = '\0';


    int nodeIdx = hash(lcWord);
    if (nodeIdx < 0)
    {
        free(lcWord);
        return false;
    }

    nodeWords *searchNode;
    searchNode = nodeArray[nodeIdx];
    bool searchContinues = true, found = false;

    // this is our binary searech

    do
    {
        if (strcmp(lcWord, searchNode->word) == 0)
        {
            searchContinues = false;
            found = true;
        }
        else if (strcmp(lcWord, searchNode->word) < 0)
        {
            if (searchNode->left == NULL)
            {
                searchContinues = false;
            }
            else
            {
                searchNode = searchNode->left;
            }
        }
        else
        {
            if (searchNode->right == NULL)
            {
                searchContinues = false;
            }
            else
            {
                searchNode = searchNode->right;
            }
        }
    }
    while (searchContinues);

    free(lcWord);
    return found;
}
unsigned int hash(const char *word)
{

    // we assume the dictionary is already sorted

    nodeWords *node;
    node = headHashNode;
    int idx = -9;
    int lc = strlen(word);;
    char *lcWord = malloc(46);
    bool rightFlag = false;
    bool leftFag = false;

    for (int i = 0; i < lc; i++)
    {

        lcWord[i] = tolower(word[i]);
    }
    lcWord[lc] = '\0';

    // printf("HASH\n");
    // printf("%s %s %s\n",lcWord, words[0],words[numberOfWords - 1]);

    if (strcmp(lcWord, words[0]) < 0 || strcmp(lcWord, words[numberOfWords - 1]) > 0)
    {
        free(lcWord);
        return -1;
    }
    do
    {
        // printf("%s %s %s %d\n",lcWord, node->word,node->wordEnd,strcmp(lcWord,node->word));

        if (strcmp(lcWord, node->word) == 0)
        {
            //printf("FOUND 0\n");
            free(lcWord);
            return node->index;

        }
        else if (strcmp(lcWord, node->word) > 0)
        {
            if (strcmp(lcWord, node->wordEnd) <= 0 || node->right == NULL)
            {
                //printf("FOUND 1\n");
                free(lcWord);
                return node->index;
            }
            // printf("RIGHT\n");


            node = node->right;



        }
        else
        {
            // printf("LEFT\n");
            if (node->left == NULL)
            {
                return -1;
            }
            else
            {
                node = node->left;
            }
        }


    }
    while (true);
}




// Loads dictionary into memory, returning true if successful else false
bool load(const char *dictionary)
{
    // messy but does the job

    // printf("enter load\n");
    //find number of bytes in dictionary file
    long int dictionarySize = findSize(dictionary);
    if (dictionarySize == -1)
    {
        //printf("File Not Found 0!\n");
        return false;
    }

    //printf("dictsize %ld\n",dictionarySize);

    //allocate memory to read in entire file
    char *data = malloc(dictionarySize + 1);

    //open dictionary file
    int filedesc = open(dictionary, O_RDONLY);
    if (filedesc < 0)
    {
        //printf("File Not Found 1!\n");
        return false;
    }
    //trying to gain load speed

    //read entire dictionary
    int bytesRead = read(filedesc, data, dictionarySize);
    close(filedesc);
    //printf("bytes %d\n",bytesRead);

    FILE *fp;
    fp = fopen("dict.txt", "w+");

    int row = 0;
    int col = 0;
    words = malloc(MAXWORDS * (LENGTH + 1));

    //parse dictionary string based on new lines and replace new line char with \0 (null)
    for (int i = 0; i < dictionarySize ; i++)
    {
        words[row][col] = data[i];
        col++;
        if (data[i] == 0x0a)
        {
            words[row][col - 1] = '\0';
            //printf("%d  %s\n", row , words[row]);
            col = 0;
            row++;
        }

    }

    //printf("col = %d %s\n",col,words[row-1] );

    if (col != 0)
    {
        words[row][col] = '\0';
        //printf("extra %d  %s\n", row , words[row]);
    }
    else
    {
        row--;
    }


    numberOfWords = row + 1;
    fclose(fp);
    free(data);

    //compute number of hash buckets
    target = (int) pow(2, ceil(log2(pow(numberOfWords, .5)))) - 1; //target = number of buckets per tri (except maybe the last one.)
    if (target == 0)
    {
        target = 1;

    }


    hashBuckets = ceil((float)numberOfWords /
                       target); //   hashBuckets = number of buckets for hash table - each bucket will point to a tri

    //printf("words %d target %d hashbuckets %d\n",numberOfWords,target,hashBuckets);

    if (hashBuckets > MAXBUCKETS)
    {
        printf("FATAL ERROR: Too many hash buckets\n");
        exit(-1);
    }
    //allocate space for hash buckets
    int cnt = 0;
    nodeHash = malloc(hashBuckets * sizeof(*nodeHash));

    for (int i =  0; i < numberOfWords ; i = i + target)
    {
        int endIdx = (i + target - 1 < numberOfWords) ? i + target - 1 : numberOfWords - 1;

        nodeHash[cnt].word = malloc((strlen(words[i]) + 1) * sizeof(char));
        strcpy(nodeHash[cnt].word, words[i]);

        nodeHash[cnt].wordEnd = malloc((strlen(words[endIdx]) + 1) * sizeof(char));
        strcpy(nodeHash[cnt].wordEnd, words[endIdx]);
        cnt++;
    }


    headHashNode = leftRightAddress(hashBuckets, nodeHash);


    int triCnt;
    cnt = 0;

    nodeArray = malloc(hashBuckets * sizeof(*nodeHash));

    nodeHistory = malloc(hashBuckets * sizeof(*nodeHash));

    for (int i = 0; i < numberOfWords; i = i + target)
    {
        nodeTri = malloc(target * sizeof(*nodeTri));
        nodeHistory[cnt] = nodeTri;


        triCnt = 0;
        for (int j = i, stopper = (i + target < numberOfWords) ? i + target : numberOfWords; j < stopper; j++)
        {
            nodeTri[triCnt].word = malloc((strlen(words[j]) + 1) * sizeof(char));
            strcpy(nodeTri[triCnt].word, words[j]);

            int endIdx = (j + target - 1 < numberOfWords) ? j + target - 1 : numberOfWords - 1;
            nodeTri[triCnt].wordEnd = malloc((strlen(words[endIdx]) + 1) * sizeof(char));
            strcpy(nodeTri[triCnt].wordEnd, words[endIdx]);

            triCnt++;
        }

        nodeArray[cnt] = leftRightAddress(triCnt, nodeTri);

        cnt++;


    }




    return true;
}

// Returns number of words in dictionary if loaded else 0 if not yet loaded
unsigned int size(void)
{
    return numberOfWords;
}

// Unloads dictionary from memory, returning true if successful else false
bool unload(void)
{
    // quick and easy

    for (int i = 0; i < hashBuckets; i++)
    {
        free(nodeHash[i].word);
        free(nodeHash[i].wordEnd);
    }
    free(nodeHash);// TODO

    int cnt = 0;

    for (int i = 0; i < hashBuckets; i++)
    {
        nodeTri = nodeHistory[i];
        for (int j = 0; j < target; j++)
        {
            if (cnt < numberOfWords)
            {
                free(nodeTri[j].word);
                free(nodeTri[j].wordEnd);
            }
            cnt++;

        }
        free(nodeTri);
    }

    free(words);

    free(nodeArray);
    free(nodeHistory);

    return true;
}
long int findSize(const char *file_name)
{


    // opening the file in read mode
    FILE *fp = fopen(file_name, "r");

    // checking if the file exist or not
    if (fp == NULL)
    {
        //printf("File Not Found!\n");
        return -1;
    }

    fseek(fp, 0L, SEEK_END);

    // calculating the size of the file
    long int size = ftell(fp);

    // closing the file
    fclose(fp);

    return size;
}

nodeWords *leftRightAddress(int buckets, nodeWords *nodeGen)
{
    //did not use recursion for speed

    bool printFlag = false;

    int numbers[buckets] ;

    for (int i = 0; i < buckets; i++)
    {
        numbers[i] = i;
    }

    int loops = (int)(log2(buckets) + .000001),
        cnt   = 0,
        oob   = 0,
        rob   = 0;

    int idx, ilx = -100, irx = -100,
             jdx, jlx = -100, jrx = -100,
                  kdx, klx = -100, krx = -100,
                       ldx, llx = -100, lrx = -100,
                            mdx, mlx = -100, mrx = -100,
                                 ndx, nlx = -100, nrx = -100,
                                      odx, olx = -100, orx = -100,
                                           pdx, plx = -100, prx = -100,
                                                qdx, qlx = -100, qrx = -100;

    int ikick = 0, ijmp = 0,
        jkick = 0, jjmp = 0,
        kkick = 0, kjmp = 0,
        lkick = 0, ljmp = 0,
        mkick = 0, mjmp = 0,
        nkick = 0, njmp = 0,
        okick = 0, ojmp = 0,
        pkick = 0, pjmp = 0,
        qkick = 0, qjmp = 0;

    int *nextBucket;
    bool oddlot = false;
    int used[buckets];

    if (buckets != (int)pow(2, loops + 1) - 1)
    {
        for (int i = 0; i < buckets; i++)
        {
            used[i] = -99;
        }
        oddlot = true;
    }


    if (printFlag)
    {
        printf("loops= %d buckets=%d  \n", loops, buckets);
    }

    for (int i = 0; i < buckets; i++)
    {
        if (printFlag)
        {
            printf("%d   %s   %p  \n", i, nodeGen[i].word, &nodeGen[i]);
        }
    }
    //comments

    for (int i = 0; i < 1; i++)
    {
        if (cnt < buckets)
        {
            idx = pow(2, loops) - 1;
            nodeGen[idx].index = idx;

            if (printFlag)
            {
                printf("index = %d  idx = %d word = %s cnt = %d \n", nodeGen[idx].index, idx, nodeGen[idx].word, cnt);
            }
            cnt ++;

            if (loops > 0)
            {
                nextBucket = nextBuckets(loops - 1, jkick, oob,  buckets);
                if (printFlag)
                {
                    printf("NEXT %d %d %s\n", nextBucket[0], nextBucket[1], nodeGen[idx].word);
                }

                nodeGen[idx].left  = &nodeGen[nextBucket[0]];
                nodeGen[idx].right = &nodeGen[nextBucket[1]];

                //printf("VALUES %f %d idx=%d i=%d\n",pow(2,loops)-1,oddlot,idx,i);

                if (idx > pow(2, loops) - 1 && oddlot)
                {
                    used[idx] = idx;
                    if (nextBucket[0] <= pow(2, loops) - 1 || used[nextBucket[0]] == nextBucket[0])
                    {
                        nodeGen[idx].left = NULL;
                    }
                }
                if (nextBucket[1] <= idx)
                {
                    nodeGen[idx].right = NULL;
                }
            }
            else
            {
                nodeGen[idx].left  = NULL;
                nodeGen[idx].right = NULL;
            }
            if (printFlag)
            {
                printf("node idx = %p %d  left: %p  %d  right: %p  %d  oob: %d  rob:  %d\n\n", &nodeGen[idx], idx, nodeGen[idx].left, ilx,
                       nodeGen[idx].right, irx, oob, rob);
            }
        }
        //comments
        for (int j = 0; j < ((buckets > 1) ? 2 : 0); j++)
        {
            if (cnt < buckets)
            {
                jdx   = pow(2, loops - 1) - 1  + jkick;
                jkick = jkick + pow(2, loops);
                if (jdx > buckets - 1 - oob)
                {
                    while (jdx > buckets - 1 - oob)
                    {
                        jdx = jdx -  1 ;
                    }
                    oob++;
                }
                nodeGen[jdx].index = jdx;
                if (printFlag)
                {
                    printf("index = %d  jdx = %d word = %s cnt = %d \n", nodeGen[jdx].index, jdx, nodeGen[jdx].word, cnt) ;
                }
                cnt ++;

                if (loops > 1)
                {
                    nextBucket = nextBuckets(loops - 2, kkick, oob,  buckets);
                    if (printFlag)
                    {
                        printf("NEXT %d %d\n", nextBucket[0], nextBucket[1]);
                    }

                    nodeGen[jdx].left  = &nodeGen[nextBucket[0]];
                    nodeGen[jdx].right = &nodeGen[nextBucket[1]];

                    if (jdx > pow(2, loops) - 1  && oddlot)
                    {
                        used[jdx] = jdx;
                        if (nextBucket[0] <= pow(2, loops) - 1 || used[nextBucket[0]] == nextBucket[0])
                        {
                            nodeGen[jdx].left = NULL;
                        }
                        if (nextBucket[1] <= jdx)
                        {
                            nodeGen[jdx].right = NULL;
                        }
                    }
                }
                else
                {
                    nodeGen[jdx].left  = NULL;
                    nodeGen[jdx].right = NULL;
                }
                if (printFlag)
                {
                    printf("node = %p %d  left: %p  %d  right: %p  %d\n\n", &nodeGen[jdx], jdx, nodeGen[jdx].left, jlx, nodeGen[jdx].right, jrx);
                }
            }
            //comments
            for (int k = 0; k < ((buckets > 3) ? 2 : 0); k++)
            {
                if (cnt < buckets)
                {
                    kdx   = pow(2, loops - 2) - 1  + kkick;
                    kkick = kkick + pow(2, loops - 1);
                    if (kdx > buckets - 1 - oob)
                    {
                        while (kdx > buckets - 1 - oob)
                        {
                            kdx = kdx -  1 ;
                        }
                        oob++;
                    }
                    nodeGen[kdx].index = kdx;
                    if (printFlag)
                    {
                        printf("index = %d  kdx = %d word = %s cnt = %d \n", nodeGen[kdx].index, kdx, nodeGen[kdx].word, cnt) ;
                    }
                    cnt ++;

                    if (loops > 2)
                    {
                        nextBucket = nextBuckets(loops - 3, lkick, oob,  buckets);
                        if (printFlag)
                        {
                            printf("NEXT %d %d\n", nextBucket[0], nextBucket[1]);
                        }

                        nodeGen[kdx].left  = &nodeGen[nextBucket[0]];
                        nodeGen[kdx].right = &nodeGen[nextBucket[1]];

                        if (kdx > pow(2, loops) - 1  && oddlot)
                        {
                            used[kdx] = kdx;
                            if (nextBucket[0] <= pow(2, loops) - 1 || used[nextBucket[0]] == nextBucket[0])
                            {
                                nodeGen[kdx].left = NULL;
                            }
                            if (nextBucket[1] <= kdx)
                            {
                                nodeGen[kdx].right = NULL;
                            }
                        }
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        nodeGen[kdx].left  = NULL;
                        nodeGen[kdx].right = NULL;
                    }
                    if (printFlag)
                    {
                        printf("node = %p %d  left: %p  %d  right: %p  %d\n\n", &nodeGen[kdx], kdx, nodeGen[kdx].left, klx, nodeGen[kdx].right, krx);
                    }
                }
                //comments
                for (int l = 0; l < ((buckets > 7) ? 2 : 0); l++)
                {
                    if (cnt < buckets)
                    {
                        ldx   = pow(2, loops - 3) - 1  + lkick;
                        lkick = lkick + pow(2, loops - 2);
                        if (ldx > buckets - 1 - oob)
                        {
                            while (ldx > buckets - 1 - oob)
                            {
                                ldx = ldx - 1;
                            }
                            oob++;
                        }
                        nodeGen[ldx].index = ldx;
                        if (printFlag)
                        {
                            printf("index = %d  ldx = %d word = %s cnt = %d \n", nodeGen[ldx].index, ldx, nodeGen[ldx].word, cnt) ;
                        }
                        cnt ++;

                        if (loops > 3)
                        {
                            nextBucket = nextBuckets(loops - 4, mkick, oob,  buckets);
                            if (printFlag)
                            {
                                printf("NEXT %d %d\n", nextBucket[0], nextBucket[1]);
                            }

                            nodeGen[ldx].left  = &nodeGen[nextBucket[0]];
                            nodeGen[ldx].right = &nodeGen[nextBucket[1]];

                            if (ldx > pow(2, loops) - 1  && oddlot)
                            {
                                used[ldx] = ldx;
                                if (nextBucket[0] <= pow(2, loops) - 1 || used[nextBucket[0]] == nextBucket[0])
                                {
                                    nodeGen[ldx].left = NULL;
                                }
                                if (nextBucket[1] <= ldx)
                                {
                                    nodeGen[ldx].right = NULL;
                                }
                            }
                        }
                        else
                        {
                            nodeGen[ldx].left  = NULL;
                            nodeGen[ldx].right = NULL;
                        }
                        if (printFlag)
                        {
                            printf("node = %p %d  left: %p  %d  right: %p  %d\n\n", &nodeGen[ldx], ldx, nodeGen[ldx].left, llx, nodeGen[ldx].right, lrx);
                        }
                    }
                    //comments
                    for (int m = 0; m < ((buckets > 15) ? 2 : 0); m++)
                    {
                        if (cnt < buckets)
                        {
                            mdx   = pow(2, loops - 4) - 1  + mkick;
                            mkick = mkick + pow(2, loops - 3);
                            if (mdx > buckets - 1 - oob)
                            {
                                while (mdx > buckets - 1 - oob)
                                {
                                    mdx = mdx - 1;
                                }
                                oob++;
                            }
                            nodeGen[mdx].index = mdx;
                            if (printFlag)
                            {
                                printf("index = %d  mdx = %d word = %s cnt = %d \n", nodeGen[mdx].index, mdx, nodeGen[mdx].word, cnt) ;
                            }
                            cnt ++;

                            if (loops > 4)
                            {
                                nextBucket = nextBuckets(loops - 5, nkick, oob,  buckets);
                                if (printFlag)
                                {
                                    printf("NEXT %d %d\n", nextBucket[0], nextBucket[1]);
                                }

                                nodeGen[mdx].left  = &nodeGen[nextBucket[0]];
                                nodeGen[mdx].right = &nodeGen[nextBucket[1]];

                                if (mdx > pow(2, loops) - 1  && oddlot)
                                {
                                    used[mdx] = mdx;
                                    if (nextBucket[0] <= pow(2, loops) - 1 || used[nextBucket[0]] == nextBucket[0])
                                    {
                                        nodeGen[mdx].left = NULL;
                                    }
                                    if (nextBucket[1] <= mdx)
                                    {
                                        nodeGen[mdx].right = NULL;
                                    }
                                }
                            }
                            else
                            {
                                nodeGen[mdx].left  = NULL;
                                nodeGen[mdx].right = NULL;
                            }
                            if (printFlag)
                            {
                                printf("node = %p %d  left: %p  %d  right: %p  %d oob: %d  rob: %d\n\n", &nodeGen[mdx], mdx, nodeGen[mdx].left, mlx,
                                       nodeGen[mdx].right, mrx, oob, rob);
                            }
                        }
                        //comments
                        for (int n = 0; n < ((buckets > 31) ? 2 : 0); n++)
                        {
                            if (cnt < buckets)
                            {
                                ndx   = pow(2, loops - 5) - 1  + nkick;
                                nkick = nkick + pow(2, loops - 4);
                                if (ndx > buckets - 1 - oob)
                                {
                                    while (ndx > buckets - 1 - oob)
                                    {
                                        ndx = ndx - 1;
                                    }
                                    oob++;
                                }
                                nodeGen[ndx].index = ndx;
                                if (printFlag)
                                {
                                    printf("index = %d  ndx = %d word = %s cnt = %d \n", nodeGen[ndx].index, ndx, nodeGen[ndx].word, cnt) ;
                                }
                                cnt ++;

                                if (loops > 5)
                                {
                                    nextBucket = nextBuckets(loops - 6, okick, oob,  buckets);
                                    if (printFlag)
                                    {
                                        printf("NEXT %d %d\n", nextBucket[0], nextBucket[1]);
                                    }

                                    nodeGen[ndx].left  = &nodeGen[nextBucket[0]];
                                    nodeGen[ndx].right = &nodeGen[nextBucket[1]];

                                    if (ndx > pow(2, loops) - 1  && oddlot)
                                    {
                                        used[ndx] = ndx;
                                        if (nextBucket[0] <= pow(2, loops) - 1 || used[nextBucket[0]] == nextBucket[0])
                                        {
                                            nodeGen[ndx].left = NULL;
                                        }
                                        if (nextBucket[1] <= ndx)
                                        {
                                            nodeGen[ndx].right = NULL;
                                        }
                                    }
                                }
                                else
                                {
                                    nodeGen[ndx].left  = NULL;
                                    nodeGen[ndx].right = NULL;
                                }
                                if (printFlag)
                                {
                                    printf("node = %p %d  left: %p  %d  right: %p  %d\n\n", &nodeGen[ndx], ndx, nodeGen[ndx].left, nlx, nodeGen[ndx].right, nrx);
                                }
                            }
                            //comments
                            for (int o = 0; o < ((buckets > 63) ? 2 : 0); o++)
                            {
                                if (cnt < buckets)
                                {
                                    odx   = pow(2, loops - 6) - 1  + okick;
                                    okick = okick + pow(2, loops - 5);
                                    if (odx > buckets - 1 - oob)
                                    {
                                        while (odx > buckets - 1 - oob)
                                        {
                                            odx = odx - 1;
                                        }
                                        oob++;
                                    }
                                    nodeGen[odx].index = odx;
                                    if (printFlag)
                                    {
                                        printf("index = %d  odx = %d word = %s cnt = %d \n", nodeGen[odx].index, odx, nodeGen[odx].word, cnt) ;
                                    }
                                    cnt ++;

                                    if (loops > 6)
                                    {
                                        nextBucket = nextBuckets(loops - 7, pkick, oob,  buckets);
                                        if (printFlag)
                                        {
                                            printf("NEXT %d %d\n", nextBucket[0], nextBucket[1]);
                                        }

                                        nodeGen[odx].left  = &nodeGen[nextBucket[0]];
                                        nodeGen[odx].right = &nodeGen[nextBucket[1]];

                                        if (odx > pow(2, loops) - 1  && oddlot)
                                        {
                                            used[odx] = odx;
                                            if (nextBucket[0] <= pow(2, loops) - 1 || used[nextBucket[0]] == nextBucket[0])
                                            {
                                                nodeGen[odx].left = NULL;
                                            }
                                            if (nextBucket[1] <= odx)
                                            {
                                                nodeGen[odx].right = NULL;
                                            }
                                        }
                                    }
                                    else
                                    {
                                        nodeGen[odx].left  = NULL;
                                        nodeGen[odx].right = NULL;
                                    }
                                    if (printFlag)
                                    {
                                        printf("node = %p %d  left: %p  %d  right: %p  %d\n\n", &nodeGen[odx], odx, nodeGen[odx].left, olx, nodeGen[odx].right, orx);
                                    }
                                }
                                //comments
                                for (int p = 0; p < ((buckets > 127) ? 2 : 0); p++)
                                {
                                    if (cnt < buckets)
                                    {
                                        pdx   = pow(2, loops - 7) - 1  + pkick;
                                        pkick = pkick + pow(2, loops - 6);
                                        if (pdx > buckets - 1 - oob)
                                        {
                                            while (pdx > buckets - 1 - oob)
                                            {
                                                pdx = pdx - 1;
                                            }
                                            oob++;
                                        }
                                        nodeGen[pdx].index = pdx;
                                        if (printFlag)
                                        {
                                            printf("index = %d  pdx = %d word = %s cnt = %d \n", nodeGen[pdx].index, pdx, nodeGen[pdx].word, cnt) ;
                                        }
                                        cnt ++;

                                        if (loops > 7)
                                        {
                                            nextBucket = nextBuckets(loops - 8, qkick, oob,  buckets);
                                            if (printFlag)
                                            {
                                                printf("NEXT %d %d\n", nextBucket[0], nextBucket[1]);
                                            }

                                            nodeGen[pdx].left  = &nodeGen[nextBucket[0]];
                                            nodeGen[pdx].right = &nodeGen[nextBucket[1]];

                                            if (pdx > pow(2, loops) - 1  && oddlot)
                                            {
                                                used[pdx] = pdx;
                                                if (nextBucket[0] <= pow(2, loops) - 1 || used[nextBucket[0]] == nextBucket[0])
                                                {
                                                    nodeGen[pdx].left = NULL;
                                                }
                                                if (nextBucket[1] <= pdx)
                                                {
                                                    nodeGen[pdx].right = NULL;
                                                }
                                            }
                                        }
                                        else
                                        {
                                            nodeGen[pdx].left  = NULL;
                                            nodeGen[pdx].right = NULL;
                                        }
                                        if (printFlag)
                                        {
                                            printf("node = %p %d  left: %p  %d  right: %p  %d\n\n", &nodeGen[pdx], pdx, nodeGen[pdx].left, plx, nodeGen[pdx].right, prx);
                                        }
                                    }
                                    //comments
                                    for (int q = 0; q < ((buckets > 255) ? 2 : 0); q++)
                                    {
                                        if (cnt < buckets)
                                        {
                                            qdx   = pow(2, loops - 8) - 1  +  qkick;
                                            qkick = qkick + pow(2, loops - 7);
                                            if (qdx > buckets - 1 - oob)
                                            {
                                                while (qdx > buckets - 1 - oob)
                                                {
                                                    qdx = qdx - 1;
                                                }
                                                oob++;
                                            }
                                            nodeGen[qdx].index = qdx;
                                            if (printFlag)
                                            {
                                                printf("index = %d  qdx = %d word = %s cnt = %d \n", nodeGen[qdx].index, qdx, nodeGen[qdx].word, cnt) ;
                                            }
                                            cnt ++;

                                            nodeGen[qdx].left  = NULL;
                                            nodeGen[qdx].right = NULL;

                                            if (printFlag)
                                            {
                                                printf("node = %p %d  left: %p  %d  right: %p  %d\n\n", &nodeGen[qdx], qdx, nodeGen[qdx].left, qlx, nodeGen[qdx].right, qrx);
                                            }
                                        }
                                    }
                                }
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }

    return (&nodeGen[idx]);
}

int *nextBuckets(int power, int kick, int oob, int buckets)
{
    //comments
    static int  next[2];

    for (int i = 0; i < 2; i++)
    {
        next[i]   = pow(2, power) - 1  + kick;
        kick = kick + pow(2, power + 1);

        if (next[i] > buckets - 1 - oob)
        {
            while (next[i] > buckets - 1 - oob)
            {
                next[i] = next[i] -  1 ;
            }
            oob++;
        }
    }
    return next;
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

## Don't read a file character by character

Reading a file a character at a time is slow. Even if standard input is buffered, then you still have the overhead of individual calls to `fgetc()`, which has to check each time if there is at least one character in the input buffer, and if so remove it from the buffer and return it, otherwise read some more data in the buffer.

The fastest way to process the file is probably to [`mmap()`](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/mmap.2.html) it, although that is not portable C. Instead, consider reading in entire lines with [`fgets()`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/io/fgets), or a few thousand bytes at a time using [`fread()`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/io/fread). Then just loop through the line/array of characters you just read.

Note that if you read in whole lines, and you know there is no hyphenation, you always know you will have read whole words, so you don't need to copy characters into `word[]` anymore, you just need to keep track of the start and end of a word.

## Don't include benchmarking code in the submission

Note that calls to `getrusage()` themselves might be expensive, so don't include that in your submissions. In fact, I would just not call `getrusage()` at all, but use an external tool like [`time`](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man1/time.1.html) or Linux's [`perf`](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Perf_(Linux)) to measure the time or CPU cycles used by your program.

## Avoid allocating memory if possible

When building the dictionary, you first allocate memory to read in the file, then allocate memory for an array of words, then memory for the hash buckets, then for each bucket you allocate some memory for the word stored in it. So basically, you have three copies of each word in memory. And that's before building the trie, which has a lot of allocations per word.

This is a huge waste of memory, and duplicating all the data is not free either. If the dictionary is larger than the input text, it is also a huge waste of effort. So, remove redundant copies and allocations as much as possible.

I also see that you call `malloc()` inside `hash()`, just for a small temporary buffer. In this case, just use a simple array:

```
char lcWord[LENGTH + 1];
```

## Faster ways to load the dictionary

The problem specification mentions that the dictionary lists all words already lexicographically sorted. Unless the text to spell check has much more words than the dictionary, I would not even bother hashing it or creating a tree from it, instead I would just `mmap()` it, and use a binary search to find words from the input in the dictionary. But let's assume we need to use only standard C functions, and that you do want to build a trie.

First, load the dictionary as you already do in memory. Note that you now have all the words in the dictionary in memory, so you don't need to copy them anymore, instead you can just create pointers into that buffer. You can replace all newlines with NUL bytes, so that all words are valid C strings.

When building the trie, you can use the fact that the dictionary is sorted.

## Hash? Trie? Both?

I struggle to understand how you index the dictionary. The `hash()` function doesn't look like a [hash function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hash_function) at all, instead it does a binary search. The point of a hash function is to avoid any kind of tree traversal. And after your `hash()` returns, then you are doing another binary search inside `check()`. I think this will get you the worst of both worlds.

The problem statement clearly says that you should implement a spell checker "using a hash table". So I would avoid using a trie at all, and just focus on writing a good hash table implementation. If you really want to use a trie, then forget about `hash()`, and just encode the dictionary as a single trie.